# How to remove hyphens and white space in between of the string?

Tags: android, tesseract, tess4j

Using `Tess4J` jars I got a set of string containing white spaces and hyphens.

```
V O D) >3 IIIIIII v .. 18:05Desks ¢ 3HOME FIND DESK FIND COLLEAGUE
  BOOKINGS0, SelfiMGiKIOSK708O4il27197097102,
  LOGSM’KIOSK’O8O47127197107682Monday, May 29 2017 Check-in Successful.
  You have successfully checked in to Desk 5555in 

 - Self-MG-KIOSK—0804-12—19-09—102

 on 0 at 

 - Loc-SM-KlOSK—0804-12-19-10-682
```

I am not able to verify the string as it gets hyphens and whites spaces in `Loc-SM-KlOSK—0804-12-19-10-682` & `Self-MG-KIOSK—0804-12—19-09—102`.

Comment: You can use String.contains(...)

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you just want to replace the hyphens with a minus sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the 2nd step of previous answer, Try substituting this

```
// REMOVE HYPHENS
String output = input.replaceAll("-","");

// REMOVE WHITESPACES
output = output.replaceAll(" ","");

// REMOVE ANOTHER STUFFS
output = output.replaceAll("—","");

// PRINT RESULTS
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This worked thanks, hyphens(-) were replace by "—" so i have replace that too and worked.

Comment: Can you please tick this as answer, If your problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
yourString.replaceAll("[- ]+", "")
```

Comment: I am getting this in return doesn't remove all hyphens
CheckinSuccessfulYouhavesuccessfullycheckedintoDesk5555inSelfMGKIOSK—0804121909102on0atLocSMKlOSK—O804—12—1910682

Comment: Looks like he needs to remove the emdashes and endashes also.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sample = "xyz-abc+";
String result = yourString.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","");
```

In sample, if you want to remove - or + sign then use this `replaceAll().

Happy Coding :)`

Comment: used this too getting in return as  "LocSMKlOSK—080412—1910682"

Answer (score 0):

## Removing WHITESPACE and HYPHENS

### 1. Get your String

```
String input= "Loc-SM-KlOSK—0804-12-19-10-682";
```

### 2. Replace all SPACES and HYPHENS

```
// REMOVE HYPHENS
String output = input.replaceAll("-","");

// REMOVE WHITESPACES
output = output.replaceAll(" ","");
```

### 3. You got it

The result will be stored in output, Just print it to test it

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), output, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: used this but didn't worked...it gave me in return as "LocSMKlOSK—080412—1910682"